# Switching automatically between 2 windows on Linux

Tags: scripting, window, focus

Hi I need to switch focus between two windows periodically and automatically (with software or w/e). Can this be achieved on linux?

Comment: What is your system, your desktop (Gnome, KDE, ...)? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There isn't anything generic? I think it runs ubuntu, I don't know about the desktop environment

Answer (score 6):

Most modern dekstops are EMWH compliant. You can use [`wmctrl`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wmctrl) to control those and the windows on them, e.g.:

```
wmctrl -a <WIN>
```

to activate a window by switching to its desktop and raising it (`<WIN>` can be various things, by default a string match on the window title, see the `wmctrl` man page).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any software to automatize the process at predefined time intervals?

Comment: @Robert I would either use a cron job for that (if they should always be running), or a small python program in a tmux script that starts the two windows process in the background and then sleeps and switches.